# Zend Framework 2: Get the path to the root directory of the application

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How do I get the path to the root directory of the application. In  Zend Framework 1 you could use the constant APPLICATION_PATH, how can we get it in Zend Framework 2? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You shouldn't need to. If you use the skeleton application, it does a `chdir()` into the application root; as such, relative paths will be made from that path. If you need a fully qualified path, call `getcwd()`.